# How to Redirect POST Request to another Route in Nodejs

Tags: ajax, node.js, redirect, post, routes

I have a nodejs server application that provides an API to a client-side application.
Previously, the app will send an AJAX request that contains an action parameter in the request object, req.body.action,  to the main route (i mean '/') to proceed an action base on this parameter.
However, I need to change/redirect the route of any AJAX POST request  from the main route, '/', to action specific route, '/{action route}'.

N.B.: I want to allow backward compatibility for  every user  that hasn't updated the client side app  to take this change in consideration. i.e, can't modify the AJAX request code for those users.

I have tried this code below but it does not work.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json() );

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    if( (req.body.action) && (req.body.action === 'action-1')){
        res.redirect(307, '/action-1');
    }
    if( (req.body.action) && (req.body.action === 'action-2')){
        res.redirect(307, '/action-2');
    }
});


app.post("/action-1", function (req, res) {
    //would have proceeded the request for action-1 here but it's not routed
});
app.post("/action-2", function (req, res) {
    //would have proceeded the request for action02 here but it's not routed
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json() );

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    if( (req.body.action) && (req.body.action === 'action-1')){
        return routes.act1(req, res);
    }
    if( (req.body.action) && (req.body.action === 'action-2')){
        return routes.act2(req, res);
    }
});

app.post("/action-1", routes.act1);
app.post("/action-2", routes.act2);
```

it's not redirect, but works.